# jquery mobile alert on link with cancel

Tags: jquery

This should be basic I haven't done it before.. you simply tap on a link, and have "Cancel" or "ok" - with current script, clicking on Cancel redirects you as well.  When it should just leave you on the current page.

This is for Mobile, should I also use .on instead?

js

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    if (confirm('click ok to continue, or cancel to stay on page')) {
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?  Please define the question better.

Comment: Clicking on Cancel should just Cancel the dialog and leave you on page.  Currently it redirects the same as clicking "confirm/ok"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `preventDefault()`:

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if (confirm('click ok to continue, or cancel to stay on page')) {

    }
});
```

Alternatively:

```
$("a").click(function(event){

    var answer = confirm('click ok to continue, or cancel to stay on page');

    if(answer){
        // go to destination
        return true;
    }else{
        // cancel
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: that did not work.  Cancel, works just fine, but Confirm does not work.